# Selecionar "Abrir com" com comando .bat

Tags: bat

Preciso abrir uma imagem qualquer através do **visualizador de imagens do Windows** (o que é padrão do **Windows 7**), porém estou utilizando o **Windows 10** e não consigo alterar o aplicativo padrão do sistema para não mais utilizar aquele **App** que é nativo no **Windows 10**, pesquisei e descobri que alterando algumas chaves de registro a opção para selecionar o visualizador antigo apareceria. Não sou administrador local do computador, então pensei em utilizar alguns comandos em **.bat** para tentar fazer isso:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo 
Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen "caminho da imagem"
```

Com esse comando deu certo, mas eu queria que ao clicar na imagem e ela fosse aberta com o visualizador antigo, e não ficar colando o caminho no **.bat**, pensei em de alguma forma quando eu selecionasse a imagem "abrir com" e selecionasse o **.bat** ele executasse e no "caminho da imagem", já alterasse para o caminho da imagem que eu cliquei, através de alguma variável ou coisa assim. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Não tem como porque você tem que alterar o registro e como você mesmo disse, não possui privilégios de administrador para isso

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, se você chama um arquivo .bat com um parâmetro na linha de comando, você pode acessá-lo através da variável `%1`, por exemplo:

`set caminhoDaImagem=%1`

Para saber como fazer passando mais parâmetros você pode verificar esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/382312/10746978).

E então, você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo 
Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen "%caminhoDaImagem%"
```

Agora, mesmo que você consiga colocar este .bat como uma das opções do menu de contexto "Abrir com:", não há garantia de que o nome do arquivo a ser aberto seja passado ao comando de execução, como diz essa outra [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442426/10746978). Pode ser que para arquivos .bat ele lide assim, ou não. Não achei documentação na internet que provasse tal comportamento. É algo que vale a pena testar. Além disso, você verificou se adicionar ao menu "Abrir com:" requer privilégios de administrador também? Ou apenas configurar o aplicativo como padrão os requer?

Por último, a solução que proponho caso nada acima funcione, é que você pode **arrastar** uma imagem para cima deste arquivo ".bat", e isso sim irá abrir o .bat com o arquivo como argumento. Claro, se essa for a solução escolhida, e caso você tenha um executável que faça exatamente o que seu bat se propõe a fazer, você pode fazer isso diretamente com o programa escolhido (ou um atalho para ele), sem precisar fazer um .bat tão simples que serviria no fim apenas de intermédio.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo o Windows 10 e lembro que uma das primeiras coisas que fiz foi alterar o programa para visualizar imagem para ficar igual ao do Windows 7. No meu caso, não tive dificuldade alguma seguindo estes dois passos:

1) Clicar com a tecla da direita em cima de qualquer imagem / abrir com / escolher outro aplicativo

[image: tela_1]

2) Selecionar o visualizador de fotos do Windows e marcar a opção para sempre usar este aplicativo para abrir arquivo `.jpg`.

[image: tela_2]

Sei que parece uma resposta óbvia, mas aqui funciona e acredito que seja mais fácil funcionar desta forma do que via script já que você não tem usuário administrador.

Answer (score 0):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Você pode tentar usar um bat que gera um HTA para abrir a imagem em tela cheia usando vbs.

---

Isso dispensa a necessidade de ter privilégios de administrador/senha/etc...

**Obs.: 1)** **Funciona no Windows 7 pedindo senha/usuário**

**Obs.: 2)** **Funciona nas versões do Windows 8, 8.1 e 10 sem pedir senha**

---

```bat
@echo off && pushd "%~dp0"

if exist "%temp%\hta_img_viewer.hta" del /q /f "%temp%\hta_img_viewer.hta" 2>&1 

rem :: cria o arquivo hta para executar o trabalho :: 
>"%temp%\hta_img_viewer.hta"^
    (
     echo/^<head^>^<hta:application id="ohta"
     echo/  applicationname="preview"
     echo/  windowstate="maximize"
     echo/  border="none"
     echo/  innerborder="no"
     echo/  caption="no"
     echo/  sysmenu="no"
     echo/  maximizebutton="no"
     echo/  minimizebutton="no"
     echo/  scroll="no"
     echo/  scrollflat="yes"
     echo/  singleinstance="yes"
     echo/  showintaskbar="no"
     echo/  contextmenu="no"
     echo/  selection="no"
     echo/^>^</head^>
     echo/ body ^{
     echo/ box-sizing: border-box;
     echo/ min-height: 0vh;
     echo/ margin: 0;
     echo/ border-bottom: solid 5px #ad3127;
     echo/ padding-top: 0px;
     echo/ ^}
     echo/ ^<script language="vbscript"^>
     echo/  sub window_onload
     echo/    document.all.splash.width = document.body.offsetwidth
     echo/    document.all.splash.height = document.body.offsetheight
     echo/  end sub
     echo/^</script^>^<body^>^<p^>^<img id='splash' src='%~f1'^>^</p^>^</body^>
    ) && start "" /b mshta.exe "%temp%\hta_img_viewer.hta"
    >nul timeout /t 4 & taskkill /f /im mshta.exe 2>&1 
    del /q /f "%temp%\hta_img_viewer.hta" 2>&1
```

---

Caso queira dar uma aprofundada em [hta](https://www.599cd.com/tips/hta/beginner/B1/):